# Postgresql : query to return only columns that do not contain only zero?

Tags: postgresql

I have one table t1 and some columns with only zero (in this case s1 and s5)

[image: see image1]

i would select only where i found some values > 0 (s2,s3,s4). 
Exist a query to return as follow?

[image: see image2]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to check first:

```
select count(1) from t where s2 > 0;
select count(1) from t where s3 > 0;
```

and so on and just exclude columns with resulting count = 0

or try to apply crosstab here